# Database event trigger by timer

Tags: php, sql

Suppose I have a table with the current users logged in on my website. And if I there isn't any "activity" from one of his/her username in a time interval it would be deleted from the table.

What would be the easiest way to implement this functionality?

Besides using batch files or something like that.

I searched but database triggers can't be timed programmed, at least from what I gathered.

I'll be using a table with the usernames and timestamps to define their latest activity and consider that those who haven't done nothing in the last 10 mins are logged of.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Scheduled or delayed actions are not something I expect from a database server.  Actions like you want are generally programmed as an external service.  Scheduling can be done using a variety of mechanisms.  Crontab is one.  For a Java application, Quartz is one option.

If you are querying the table to determine if someone is logged in, I would consider using a view including the relative time limit in the selection criteria.  Date arithmetic is common database functionality.  This would make cleaning up the table less time critical.

Oracle has a Jobs facility that is basically a crontab service provided by the database server. I don't know of any other databases with similar functionality.